# Error when try to download file from Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, downloadfileasync

I tried to download a file from Azure Data Lake. With the credentials, I can list the contents of the directory. But Downloading gives below error:
"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission"

The code used:

```
TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantID, clientID, clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions());
    
string dfsUri = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
               
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), credential);
    
DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemClient("DAIP_Data");
    
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
                    fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("DAIP/System2");
    
DataLakeFileClient fileClient =
                    directoryClient.GetFileClient("System2_iDoc_20211229182731_06e34fa6-f683-4568-8a5d-5ae30eac50b6.xml");
    
Response<FileDownloadInfo> downloadResponse = await fileClient.ReadAsync();
```

Any suggestion/ help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error: `This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission`

you need to provide enough permission to storage account like `storage blob data contributor` or `storage blob data owner` then you can fix this issue.

As per [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#verify-role-assignments):

[image: Ref1]

**Adding role-assignments follow below steps:**

[image: Ref2]

[image: Ref3]